# Compiler says about redifinition error, but functions where mentiones just in header and C++ file

Tags: c++

When I described prototypes of functions in header file and implemented functions at MoveMatrix.cpp, I got error: compiler says "error: redifinition of nc::NdArray translate(float, float, float)", although I hadnt described or even mention this functions int other files besides MoveMatrix.h. I have got error from 4 line of MoveMatrix.cpp!

This is MoveMatrix.h

```
//MoveMatrix.h
#pragma once
#include<NumCpp.hpp>

nc::NdArray<float> translate(float trX, float trY, float trZ) {};
nc::NdArray<float> rotation_X(float angle) {};
nc::NdArray<float> rotation_Y(float angle) {};
nc::NdArray<float> rotation_Z(float angle) {};
nc::NdArray<float> scale(float scale_coeff) {};
```

This is MoveMatrix.cpp

```
//MoveMatrix.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "MoveMatrix.h"

nc::NdArray<float> translate(float trX, float trY, float trZ)
{
    return nc::NdArray<float>{
        {1, 0, 0, 1},
        {0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0},
        {trX, trY, trZ, 1}
    };
}

nc::NdArray<float> rotation_X(float angle)
{
    return nc::NdArray<float>{
        {1, 0, 0 , 0},
        {0, cos(angle), sin(angle), 0},
        {0, -sin(angle), cos(angle), 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1}
    };
}

nc::NdArray<float> rotation_Y(float angle)
{
    return nc::NdArray<float>{
        {cos(angle), 0, -sin(angle), 0},
        {0, 1, 0, 0},
        {sin(angle), 0, cos(angle), 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1}
    };
}
nc::NdArray<float> rotation_Z(float angle)
{
    return nc::NdArray<float>{
        {cos(angle), sin(angle), 0 , 0},
        {-sin(angle), cos(angle), 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 1}
    };
}

nc::NdArray<float> scale(float scale_coeff)
{
    return nc::NdArray<float>{
        {scale_coeff, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, scale_coeff, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, scale_coeff, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, scale_coeff}
    };
}
```

Comment: `#pragma once`  (or include guards if you want an approach supported by the standard) only protect from issues related to multiple inclusion in one compilation unit (aka source file).     Your header defines the functions, and those definitions are not inline, so your code has an ODR violation if the header is included in multiple compilation units in your project.

Comment: Incidentally, by defining them with a body of `{}` each function will cause undefined behaviour, even if you resolve the ODR concern.   Falling off the end of a function with a return type also causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suffixed `{}` means that the functions *are* defined in the header. Thus the one definition rule is violated, and compilation will fail. Remove them to convert the statements to forward declarations.

In other words,

```
nc::NdArray<float> translate(float trX, float trY, float trZ) {};
```

becomes

```
nc::NdArray<float> translate(float trX, float trY, float trZ);
```

and so on.

Comment: OOOH I FORGOT ABOUT THAT... THANK YOU VERY MUCH